# Type hint a SQLAlchemy 2 declarative model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I create my SQLAlchemy models in [the 2.0 way](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html):

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
```

I'm writing a function which does something to one of these models:

```py
def drop_table(model):
    model.__table__.drop()
```

How can I type hint `model` here, such that my type hinter will:

1. Know which methods `model.__table__` has got?
2. Accept `drop_table(User)`?

I naively assumed I could do:

```py
def drop_table(model: Base):
    ...
```

but that gives me:

> "Type[DeclarativeAttributeIntercept]" is incompatible with "Type[Base]"

Comment: The methods provided by the `__table__` attribute depends on the actual *value* of `model`, not its type.

Comment: Interesting. @chepner, could you expand and maybe give an example?

Comment: The static type of `__tablename__` is `str`, which doesn't tell you anything about the methods available to the actual type that represents the table a particular table name refers to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the perfect answer so far, but here's the best I can do:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import MappedClassProtocol
from sqlalchemy import Table

def drop_table(model: MappedClassProtocol):
    table: Table = model.__table__  # type: ignore
    model.__table__.drop()

drop_table(User) # this type checks ok
```

So `MappedClassProtocol` allows the function to accept an ORM model, but unfortunately `model.__table__` doesn't appear as a `Table` so we've got to do one `# type: ignore`.

Can anyone improve on this?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similar to what you're doing, without `# type: ignore` but rather an `assert` check.

From searching the SQLAlchemy source code, it looks like that's the way they do it internally - that's the main info I wanted to share. So I'm probably going to use this for now.

```py
def drop_table(model: MappedClassProtocol):
    assert isinstance(model.__table__, Table)
    model.__table__.drop()
```

Which type-checks fine. But I guess for some constructs you could get an `AssertionError` that mypy hasn't detected.